# React Router Dom Private Route not Working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to implement a private route towards my application, and while it correctly reaches the private route when authenticated, it redirects it to the login page rather than the children. I've tried every solution on stackoverflow but they don't seem to work. It's strange because it reaches the right path (I print to console whenever I reach the private route) but it's not able to redirect the page correctly.

PrivateRoute

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRef } from 'react';
import { Outlet, Navigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import Axios from "axios";
import Cookies from "universal-cookie";

export default function ProtectedRoute({ children }) {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState();
  // add loading state, initially true for initial render
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const checkAuth = async () => {
    const cookie = new Cookies(); 
    setIsLoading(true); // <-- set true when starting auth check
    try {
      if (cookie.get("stytch_session") == null) {
        console.log("no cookies!")
        setIsAuthenticated(false);
      } else {
        Axios.post(
          "http://localhost:5001/test",
          {},
          { headers: { sessiontoken: cookie.get("stytch_session") } }
        )
          .then((response) => {
            console.log("reaching private route!")
            setIsAuthenticated(true);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
            setIsAuthenticated(false);
          });
      }
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false); // <-- clear loading state when completed
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    checkAuth();
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div className="">Loading...</div>;
  }

  return isAuthenticated ? children : <Navigate to={"/login"} />;

}
```

And here is the code snippet that's called in app.js

```
<Route
  path="/scroll"
  element={(
    <ProtectedRoute>
      <Scroll /> 
    </ProtectedRoute>
  }
/>
```

Comment: The way I like to do redirects in React is by using the built in `window` variable, for an easy URL redirect just do `window.location.href = "/private";` and it will redirect just fine.

Comment: I don't think this really fixes my problem because even though it seems to ignore the truth/false value of isAuthenticated and goes to the login page regardless...

Comment: @jasonmzx Doing redirects like that will reload the entire page, in other words, the entire app will be remounted. Most people don't like doing that since it's unnecessary and completely avoidable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `axios.post` starts an asynchronous Promise chain that the synchronous code around it doesn't wait for. The `finally` block is executed prior to the POST request resolving.

The code should `await` the Promise to resolve.

```
export default function ProtectedRoute() {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState();

  // add loading state, initially true for initial render
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  const checkAuth = async () => {
    const cookie = new Cookies(); 
    setIsLoading(true);

    try {
      if (cookie.get("stytch_session") == null) {
        console.log("no cookies!")
        setIsAuthenticated(false);
      } else {
        await Axios.post(
          "http://localhost:5001/test",
          {},
          { headers: { sessiontoken: cookie.get("stytch_session") } }
        );
        console.log("reaching private route!")
        setIsAuthenticated(true);
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
      setIsAuthenticated(false);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    checkAuth();
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div className="">Loading...</div>;
  }

  return isAuthenticated ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
}
```

```
<Route element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
  <Route path="/scroll" element={<Scroll />} />
  ... other protected routes ...
</Route>
```

Comment: Tried adding in the extra const response await part but I'm not able to do so without getting the compiler error "Missing initializer in const declaration." Is there another way to await the axios call?

Comment: Actually sorry nevermind, forgot to add in the "=" in between response and await. Works perfectly now, thank you!!

Comment: @kruskal123 Ah, sorry, typo on my part. Actually, since it doesn't appear that the UI code needs the `response` for anything you could also just simply `await Axios.post(....)`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using Outlet if your private route is child of `ProtectedRoute` component? Like following.

```
return isAuthenticated ? <Outlet />: <Navigate to={"/login"} />;
```

Comment: Just tried it and it doesn't change anything unfortunately...

Comment: @kruskal123 You wrap your private route like this `<Route path='/protected-route-path' element={<ProtectedRoute/>}><Route path='/private-route-path' element={<PrivateRoute/>}><.Route>`? Since I've developed same type app as  yours and it workd perfectly.

Comment: Sorry can you double check the syntax, I'm not sure if the routes in your code  are closed properly. Here is the route that I put in my code: <Route path="/scroll" element={
            <ProtectedRoute>
              <Scroll /> 
              </ProtectedRoute>
            } /> (Where scroll is the protected path)

Comment: ...</Route> is correct, sorry for that. But I understood your structure. ProtectedRoute must re-render by firing setIsAuthenticated(true). Does it actually reaches there?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the finally and putting in

```
useEffect(()=>{
   if(isAuthenticated !== null){
   setIsLoading(false);
   }
},[isAuthenticated])
```

What it looks like to me is that your state updates are being batched or resolving in the wrong order. This will ensure that isLoading remains true until isAuthenticated has a real value.

Comment: FWIW, batched or not, React state updates are ***always*** processed in the order they are enqueued in. They aren't `async` so there's nothing to "resolve".

Comment: I'm not able to add in that function as it gives me a "React Hook "useEffect" is called in function "checkAuth" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use"  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks" error

Comment: @kruskal123 did you put it in the same place rather than with your other useEffect? It goes with the other one. Ultimately this would have the same effect as the await but rather than waiting it uses the update as a trigger.